# returning json path in controller MVC

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework

I have a stored procedure that returns a json path :

```
GO

alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_getjsondata](


@type  INT                 

)
AS
BEGIN

SELECT
          [Time] as 'Time',
          cast([Value] as varchar(10)) as 'Value'
      FROM [dbo].[tbl_data] where type = @type
      for JSON PATH

END
```

the stored procedure is returning the following:
 [image: Result]

In the controller i have written the following code:

```
var json = entities.Database.SqlQuery("exec usp_getjsondata  @type",
               new SqlParameter("@type", type)
        ).ToList();
```

The json data is not being stored in the variable json.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: Show us the full definition for the stored procedure, in particular how its parameters are defined.

Comment: @Amy i have updated my question

Comment: Try removing the word "exec" from your code.  Just speculation, but that may be the issue.

Comment: i need exec to execute the stored procedure. To return the result

Comment: It's not needed when used from .Net.  `entities.Database.SqlQuery("usp_getjsondata...`

Comment: oh really. didn't know that. let me give it a try. thanks

Comment: Its still not working:(

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure.  It's something else then.

Comment: The path returned is json format. Maybe im not storing it properly. Maybe variable isnt the right way to go?

Comment: I don't know, sorry.  I've never used `JSON PATH` queries in conjuction with EF.  But we do use SPROCS with EF, and we do it without the `EXEC` keyword.  So I thought that might be it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my answer for anyone stuck on this,

FOR JSON will return a single record with a nvarchar(max) field containing the JSON-formatted results.

```
string json = string.Concat(entities.Database.SqlQuery("exec usp_getjsondata  @type",
    new SqlParameter("@type", type)
));
```

You can convert that back to a list of objects, then you'll need to parse the JSON:

```
var results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Class>>(json);
```

However, if want to do that, then it would be better to remove the FOR JSON from the stored procedure, and load the results directly into the list:

```
var results = entities.Database.SqlQuery<Class>("exec usp_getdata @type",
    new SqlParameter("@type", type)
).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for somiting to help beginers about this solution and help more people with this question. Here a completely solution to abstract a Factory to help use the FOR JSON PATH easily (i hope).

```
namespace DB {
    public class DbFactory
    {
        public static T ExecForJson<T>(string query, params object[] parans) where T : new()
        {
            var obj = new T();

            using (var db_ = new DbEntities())
            {

                obj = ExecForJson<T>(db_, query, parans);}
            
            
            return obj;
        }
        
        public static T ExecForJson<T>(DbEntities db_, string query, params object[] parans) where T : new()
        {
            var json = string.Concat(db_.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query, parans).ToList());

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(json)) return new T();

            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
        }

        public static System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter Param(string name, object value)
        {
            return new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter(name, value);
        }
    }
}
```

To use like this:

```
var id = 123;
//like this (create new instance)
var itens = DB.DbFactory.ExecForJson<List<Item>>("SELECT  * FROM Items WHERE ID = @ID FOR JSON PATH;", DB.DbFactory.Param("@ID", id));

//or like this (with current instance)
var itens = DB.DbFactory.ExecForJson<List<Item>>(db, "SELECT  * FROM Items WHERE ID = @ID FOR JSON PATH;", DB.DbFactory.Param("@ID", id))
```